# Reset Blockquote CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to completely reset all CSS surrounding the 'blockquote' element so I can style it myself, but I'm seeing -webkit- properties in Chrome's inspect tool which tells me that there could easily be all sorts of unknown properties throughout various browsers.

Is there a consistent, cross-browser solution to reset all CSS surrounding blockquotes?

Comment: Many of those non-standard properties are just how browsers implement certain things internally. You're never supposed to modify them yourself, even as part of a reset.

Comment: I don't want to use a class, I want to use blockquotes...no offense intended, but I'm not asking whether it's considered proper, I'm asking how to do it.

Comment: Ah, my point was that there probably isn't a consistent, cross-browser solution, because the concept behind those prefixed properties goes against that.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well....*sigh*

Comment: The question is too vague: “reset” can mean different things. Should properties be set to initial values, or to browser defaults, or to some specific values (which?). And what would it mean to reset *unknown* properties?

Answer (score 5):

Use like this:

```
blockquote, q{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}
```

And if you are checking cross browser solution like -webkit- then you should have a search

[vendor prefixes](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=vendor+prefixes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=ejZvUv-SMYOErAeS5YHQBw)